# Why doesn't QuickVPN on the RV082 work anymore?

Tags: cisco, linksys, cisco-vpn

Anyone know why users who were able to access the VPN on a Linksys RV082 router via the QuickVPN client would no longer work? Below is a screen shot of the error message that users are receiving. We've tried this with three different users, and we've confirmed user names and passwords.

#### Changes that may have impacted QuickVPN to no longer work

- Users are now running Windows XP Pro SP3, whereas previously they were running XP SP2 with the Windows hotfix KB889527 for the firewall
- User have upgraded to QuickVPN v 1.3.0.3 — We have confirmed that the older version of QuickVPN is also not working at this time
- A second RV082 was installed in a remote location and a gateway to gateway VPN connection was created so that the two subnets both appear inside our corporate intranet

#### Next Actions / Possible Remedies to Try

- Dump the log from various users' QuickVPN clients
- Find Windows XP SP2 client; install the firewall hotfix; install latest QuickVPN

#### Potentially Related Discussions

- [Linksys RV082 woes](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1236042&page=1) discussion on Tek-tips forums
- [RV082 Firewall blocks Quick VPN](http://forums.linksysbycisco.com/linksys/board/message?board.id=Wired_Routers&message.id=10868) discussion on Linksys by Cisco forum, posted on 30-Oct-06
- [RV082 and QuickVPN](https://www.myciscocommunity.com/thread/4403) discussion on Cisco Community forum, posted on 12-Aug-09
- [Quickvpn problems connecting to Linksys RV082](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/remark,15406418) discussion on DSLReports.com, posted on 05-Feb-06
- [RV082 QuickVPN trouble, remote gateway is not responding](http://forums.linksysbycisco.com/linksys/board/message?board.id=Wired_Routers&thread.id=21929) discussion on Linksys by Cisco forum, posted on 09-Jan-09

[QuickVPN Error http://img.skitch.com/20100105-j5h9ixfmajnmejiry987ykts95.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100105-j5h9ixfmajnmejiry987ykts95.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

**Update February 1, 2010:** The problem appears to have been a hardware failure in the RV082, as QuickVPN is now working after replacing the RV082 with a new unit, identically configured. If I had to guess, I'd say that it was caused by a lightning strike, so I'm not blaming Linksys/Cisco for a defective unit.

### Background/Analysis

We now have two sites each with their own RV082 providing a connection to the internet, so I have another test site. I am able to get QuickVPN to work on RV082 #2, so I think the problem is either:

1. <strike>RV082 #1 has some setting configured incorrectly</strike> **Update January 29, 2010:** I went through every page on the RV082 web management and configured the two routers identically (except for things like static IP address of the WAN, which have to be different), so this doesn't appear to be the problem.
2. RV082 #1 is damaged such that the VPN is not working even though internal routing is fine. (We know that we took a lightning strike last year, but that didn't seem to be at the same as when the QuickVPN stopped working.) **Update February 1, 2010:** Changed out the grey market RV082 #1 with a new RV082 configured exactly as the old one. QuickVPN is now working again.

### RV082 #2 Successful Configuration

- QuickVPN Client 1.3.0.3
- RV082 Firmware Ver. 2.0.0.19-tm (Feb 20 2009 15:15:20)
- RV082 S/N DEZ006100379

### RV082 #1 (Failed Unit) Unsuccessful Configuration

- QuickVPN Client 1.3.0.3
- RV082 Firmware Ver. 2.0.0.19-tm (Feb 20 2009 15:15:20)
- RV082 S/N DEZ005A01690

### RV082 #3 (Replaced RV082 #1) Successful Configuration

- QuickVPN Client 1.3.0.3
- RV082 Firmware Ver. 2.0.0.19-tm (Feb 20 2009 15:15:20)
- RV082 S/N AEZ28J800877